# Slow performances of PrimeFaces' updateFormStateInput with Internet Explorer

Tags: primefaces

We have an application which displays a (complex) table of (~500) rows  which can be edited via a modal dialog (PrimeFaces). Displaying the table (or doing any *ajaxy* things like changing some status on save buttons) takes much more time in IE9+ (5-6s) than in Chrome or Firefox (< 1s).

In the Internet Explorer's profiler, I see that most of the time is taken by the `JQuery.attr()` method which is called by PrimeFaces' `updateFormStateInput()`.

[image]

I really don't know how to go deeper in identifying the cause of this problem or if this bad performance is considered normal for IE.

Switching to Chrome/Firefox is not an option as our users have other applications that only work with IE (sharepoint).

So, is there anything I can do to solve/identify the problem? (Except removing each component one by one and see if this improves performances.)

Comment: Tried a newer PF version? And why is removing the components not an option? Sounds like you do know how to dig deeper into this but do not want to... Please elaborate

Comment: I tried with PF6.0 but that didn't do anything. And yes, you're right about digging deeper: this is code I inherited which is very messy and I am very reluctant to touch it (especially for IE-related problems). I had hoped for some answer like _Hey, that's a known problem when you do X and Y, try doing Z and everything will be fine_... but thanks for bringing me back to reality!